# htaccess Set the Content-Disposition header conditionally for PDF files

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, content-disposition

I have a script made with PHP and JavaScript that with an API generates a PDF.

The domain has a `.htaccess` in which indicates that the PDF will be "downloaded".

```
  <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
      Header set Content-Disposition "Attachment"
      Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  </FilesMatch>
```

Can I somehow keep the domain configuration and exclude the PDF file that is generated so that it can be viewed with the browser's built-in PDF viewer, rather than the browser prompting to download/save the file?

If I generate a new `.htaccess` file in the directory where the PDF is written, that `.htaccess` will only affect it, right?

Comment: Nope, all such distributed configuration files will affect your response, all found on the path up to the folder where your main script resides. That is how apache works. You _could_ overwrite headers you set prior however, but that is not exactly elegant, is it? I wonder why that `FilesMatch` directive is applying its `Header` directives here at all though. Since your requests certainly does not request a resource named "...pdf", or does it?

Comment: In the directory there is a file called "file.pdf" and what the script does is overwrite that file on each execution of the script.

I have tried creating a new htaccess inside the directory where I set the pdfs to be inline.

<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
      Header set Content-Disposition "inline"
    </FilesMatch>

And I can now view file.pdf online without downloading it.

But in the rest of the domain if I try to open in any directory the pdfs are downloaded as indicated by the root htaccess.

Is it wrong?

Comment: That is a very strange setup. Usually a URL that downloads a document is _not_ using a path that appears to be pointing to a physical file. What for? Directly request the _script_ creating the document and return the document as a response to the request. And if the creation is asynchronous, for example because creating the document takes to long, then even better: just implement a simple router script handing out the document. But stop targeting physical files via a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried creating a new htaccess inside the directory where I set the pdfs to be inline. `<FilesMatch "\.pdf$"> Header set Content-Disposition "inline" </FilesMatch>` And I can now view `file.pdf` online without downloading it. But in the rest of the domain if I try to open in any directory the pdfs are downloaded as indicated by the root htaccess. Is it wrong?

No, that's not wrong. It's perfectly acceptable to override the header in a subdirectory (more specific) `.htaccess` file in this way. (*Aside:* You could potentially `unset` the header instead, since `inline` is the default value when omitted.)

The alternative is to set the header conditionally in the parent config, based on the URL-path.

#### Set the header conditionally

For example, when the URL-path does *not* match the regex `^/directory($|/)` (requires Apache 2.4):

```
# /.htaccess

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#^/directory($|/)#">
    <FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
        Header set Content-Disposition "Attachment"
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    </FilesMatch>
</If>
```

Where `/directory` is the URL-path *prefix* to exclude.

(Although you'd probably want to set the `X-Content-Type-Options` header regardless of location.)

Note, however, that this is now based on the URL-path, not the file-path (as with using a second `.htaccess` file), if they happen to be different.

---

#### Alternative using mod_setenvif (Apache 2.2+):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/directory($|/)" INLINE_FILE
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
    Header set Content-Disposition "Attachment" env=!INLINE_FILE
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</FilesMatch>
```

The `SetEnvIf` directive sets the `INLINE_FILE` env var if a URL-path  is requested that matches the stated regex (ie. the directory to exclude). The `Content-Disposition` header is then set conditionally if the `INLINE_FILE` env var is *not* set (as denoted by the `!` prefix).

Answer (score 0):

> "Can I .... can be viewed in the browser without downloading?"

No. HTTPS (replaces FTPS) is TEXT TRANSFER in other words ALL web materials need to be dis-positioned from a file server to a browsing screen based word processor as text, where it is edited into a clients display system.

There are NO exceptions, unless you do not transmit. The concept of an attachment can be shown inline is a throwback to difference between plain text and html emails, the html has the attachment in all cases however :-

> an email message may contain inline images within its body as well as regular attachments associated with it.

Specifically for PDF with(in) a html text the PDF attachment which is a binary application/pdf needs to run independent of the web page as binary objects in the clients CPU to be edited into **optional** frame embedded screen pixel objects, and at the same time produce editable text for searching / displaying the letters as word groups.